# How determine date format in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, date-format

I want to know in MATLAB which is the date pattern used by Excel. This is because I read an Excel file from MATLAB, but depending of the user machine locate the date is represented as dd-mm-yyyy or mm-dd-yyyy.

CLARIFICATION: Sorry for my bad explanation. This is my scenario. I have an Excel file with dates (and other collumns, no relevant for this problem).  I have two computers, which need to run my matlab application. In the first one when I use xlsread (in MATLAB) the dates appears in dd-mm-yyyy format due to the regional configuration of my computer.  In the second one, I read the same file, in the same MatLab version, but the readed dates are in mm-dd-yyyy format (again, due to the regional configuration of computer 2, which is different from computer 1).

Now, when I try to use datenum, to date transformation, I cant use formatIn parameter in a right way, because if I specify the formatIn equals to mm-dd-yyyy this will Works correctly in computer 1, by not in computer 2, and vice versa.

So, I think that I need to identify in MATLAB which is the date pattern used by Excel in the computer, in order to find the right input parameter for formatIn.

Comment: So really what you want is a way to pass the Excel Config to MATLAB so it knows what format to use?

Answer (score 1):

It is impossible to do unless you know your data really well. For instance if you have yearly readings for 01/07/20XX, it is impossible to know if it is 7th Jan or 1st July.

However, you can try the following:

```
MyString='01-23-2012';
FirstTwo=str2num(MyString(1:2));
if(FirstTwo>12)
    display('DD/MM');
else
    display('MM/DD');
end
```

If the first two digits of the date are greater than 12, then you can probably conclude that you have DD/MM/YYYY. You can loop this over all your dates.

Answer (score 1):

If you're talking about an actual .xls file, I don't know enough to say if there's a some flag for this kind of thing, but one heuristic approach (and possibly the only approach with a CSV format) would be to look for numbers greater than 12. That will immediately tell you which format you have, because such a number can't be correspond to a month. Of course, with a small data set, this isn't reliable (strictly, it's never perfectly reliable, but with non-trivial data, it's highly likely to work).

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I think that this approach Is very riskly.

Comment: Totally true, it's highly dependent on your data set. (realize that if you find a number greater than 12 in ANY date, you can general that)

Answer (score 1):

You may be able to do something with Java to tell you the date format.

```
>> import java.text.DateFormat;
>> import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
>> df = DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.SHORT);
>> dateFormat = char(df.toPattern())
dateFormat =
dd/MM/yy
```

I think xlsread uses this format, although you'll need to test it on both of your machines.
Note there is also a Locale input to getDateInstance that may be useful.

Comment: Hello. 
When I run your code the result is
dateFormat =

d/MM/yy

So, I try using 
import java.text.DateFormat;
df = DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.SHORT, java.util.Locale.getDefault());
char(df.toPattern())

But the result is the same :(.

Comment: The result shown in MatLab is d/MM/yy, in the computer with the dd-mm-yyyy excel date format (the separator is not important)

Answer (score 0):

I am kind of confused by your question, both MATLAB and Excel are able to easily support mm-dd and dd-mm. In excel, the default will depend on where you live. In America, it will be mm-dd, and in Europe (and probably most of the rest of the world), it will be dd-mm.

In MATLAB, I am not sure if it is location dependent like Excel is, as an American, the standard is of course mm-dd, but you can fully customize how matlab parses date strings!

Check out http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/datenum.html and then go to input arguments, then "formatIn", it will provide you a list of ways to read in dates and convert it to a serial date number. (or vector if you want)

**EDIT:**

Nevermind, I misunderstood your question

Comment: Hello. Thanks for your help. In this point, The problem Is just how determinate the formatIn parameter, because in one machine this will be 'dd-mm-yyyy' , and in the other will be 'mm-dd-yyyy'.

Comment: You can't do it! For example, I am going to tell you two dates, now you tell me what date format it is in. Here are the dates: 10-11-12, the other date is 04-05-13. Now am I using mm-dd or dd-mm? Good question isn't it. You are asking MATLAB to do the EXACT same thing I just asked you to do, and as you see, it can't be done with the given information.

Comment: Please read my clarification. May be imposible to determine this based only in the data (as in your example) but you can ask To Excel the local date format used in the machine where MatLab is running.

Answer (score 0):

I run into the same issue with computers from Australia and USA.
This is a way around but it is a clean solution.
In excel convert date to text for example 
in International format 'yyyymmdd'

```
 % B1=TEXT(A1,"yyyymmdd") % This is in excel
    % in matlab read excel file 'dates.xlsx'
    [data, dates_header] =xlsread('dates.xlsx');
    % use datevec to read-in data
    t = datevec(dates_header(:,2),'yyyymmdd');
```